# What does 'subject' mean in the following passage?

Tags: meaning

> "...Plenty of biographers dramatize their narratives with descriptions
>   of emotions, highly coloured scene-setting, or strategies of suspense.
>   Some go further, and deploy full-scale fictional methods: invented
>   meetings between author and **subject**, imaginary episodes, musings on
>   the identity of the biographer, and hypothetical conversations."

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The quotation is from _Biography: A Very Short Introduction_ by Hermione Lee.

Answer (score 1):

"Subject" refers here to the person whose biography the biographer is writing: so it might be written like it's a casual conversation over coffee, when it didn't actually happen like that.

Comment: Good answer, I hope you don't mind that I made a minor edit for clarity

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime 